# Two unaligned Pandas Series: concat raises error, adding does not but it returns a weird answer

Tags: pandas

*Note: I am working with a rather old-ish Pandas `0.16.2`, in Python 2.7.11.*

My simplistic conceptual model for the adding of two `Series` was that it would involve an index-matching step that is similar to what goes on in a `pd.concat(..., axis=1)`, ie. the `Series` indexes are lined up and then the values are added.

Therefore (modulo `NaN` handling I guess), I would expect `u+v` to work if, and only if `concat([u, v], axis=1)` works.

In the example below I build two `Series` with 'unalignable' indexes. My confusion is that `concat` does raise an error (as expected) but the adding does not -- and even more confusing is that the result of adding comes back with everything duplicated.

First I create a couple of series which have equal indexes (containing duplicates):

```
import string, pandas as pd

# Create a series with an index that has duplicates
u = pd.Series(range(5), index=list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:5])
u = pd.concat([u, u])

# Create another, same index but values reversed
v = pd.Series(range(5)[::-1], index=list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:5])
v = pd.concat([v, v])
```

Here they are:

```
In [2]: u
Out[2]:
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
dtype: int64

In [3]: v
Out[3]:
a    4
b    3
c    2
d    1
e    0
a    4
b    3
c    2
d    1
e    0
dtype: int64
```

They can be added since the indices are equal:

```
In [4]: u+v
Out[4]:
a    4
b    4
c    4
d    4
e    4
a    4
b    4
c    4
d    4
e    4
dtype: int64
```

If we sort `v` then its index gets reordered and since there is no longer an obvious way to line up `v` with `u` any more it is not surprising that `concat` raises an error:

```
In [5]: v.sort()

In [6]: v
Out[6]:
e    0
e    0
d    1
d    1
c    2
c    2
b    3
b    3
a    4
a    4
dtype: int64

In [7]: pd.concat([u, v], axis=1)
....
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

However, adding still works but bizarrely returns a longer series:

```
In [8]: u+v
Out[8]:
a    4
a    4
a    4
a    4
b    4
b    4
b    4
b    4
c    4
c    4
c    4
c    4
d    4
d    4
d    4
d    4
e    4
e    4
e    4
e    4
dtype: int64
```

What happened here?

Comment: it's not very clear - what are you trying to accomplish? Could you post your desired data set?

Comment: I was expecting either: to see an error (like I get with concat ) or to see a 10-long series of 4s (like I got from adding before the sort on v).

Comment: if you want to add a column `pd.concat(..., axis=1)`, you can do it this way: `u.to_frame('u').assign(v=v.sort_values().values)`

Comment: My question is not about adding a column. My question is whether anyone has insight into why the sum operation `u+v` did not raise an error (which I expected it to) nor did it produce the right answer (a length-10 series of `4`s).